# Find $\bigcup^{m=1}_{\infty} \bigcap\limits_{n \geq m}A_{n}$ where

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove $\bigcap^{m=1}_{\infty} \bigcup\limits_{n \geq m}A_{n} = (-4,0)$

where
$A_{n} = (-3 +(-1)^n,0)$

I can't come up with any formal proof which uses inclusions.
I'd be glad to see that kind of proof.

Comment: Try to see that $$\bigcup_{n\geq m} A_n = ]-4,0[$$ for all $m\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $m\in\mathbb N$, each $A_n$, with $n\geqslant m$ is either $(-2,0)$ (when $n$ is even) or $(-4,0)$ (when $n$ is odd). Therefore, $\bigcup_{n\geqslant m}A_n=(-4,0)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sure, thank you